# making app that can change .DOCX metadata with Python

Tags: python, docx

i'm very new in codding and i need help. i wanna make an app that can change .DOCX metadata, i can do it manually but i wanna share with my friend that did not know anything about code, and i want to make it using Python, since Python is language that i hear the most.

Here is the problem:

I want to change multiple content of the tag in multiple xml file i.e.

```
core.xml:
<dc:creator>griz</dc:creator>
<cp:lastModifiedBy>mi</cp:lastModifiedBy>

app.xml:
<TotalTime>3</TotalTime>
```

I want to change the "griz" the "mi" and the "3" to something that user put in txt file (there is one txt file that contain creator name etc btw.)
the content of txt file that i wanna use is looks something like this:

```
creator name: #user answer
last editor: #user answer
total editing time: #user answer
```

does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What part do you need help with? Reading the docx file? Parsing the XML? Replacing the values?

Comment: @Aziz replace the value of the tag in multiple xml file with certain part of txt file

Comment: Use `glob` to go  scan file,  `pip install lxml` then probably use xpath to find proper tag.